# how to add location of user's dynamically in bing map api

Tags: javascript, api, bing-maps, reverse-geocoding, geocode

> I am using Bing maps API and in that i am giving location (latitude & longitude) manually in GetMap function for reverse geocode so that i can get address name

```
function GetMap() {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
        credentials: 'AslSzT37W6m8TEyrfWNFWOi-yLdclSoXdv0j',
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location( 22.6589, 78.5589), #manually putting lat&Log
        
    });
    //Make a request to reverse geocode the center of the map.
    reverseGeocode();
}
```

> Now instead of giving location manually in GetMap function i am taking user's location by below code which returns latitude & longitude

```
//Request the user's location
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(
    position.coords.latitude,
    position.coords.longitude);

// Add a pushpin at the user's location.
var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(loc);
map.entities.push(pin);
        
//Center the map on the user's location.
map.setView({ center: loc, zoom: 15 });

//printing users location name in console
console.log(loc);
});
```

> Now i want to do is to put this User's latitude & longitude in GetMap function

```
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location( 22.0365682, 78.9255313), # want to put User's Log&Lat dynamically
```

> so that i can reverse geocode of User's and get the address name

Answer (score 0):

> First i am requesting user for the location and taking user's location (latitude and longitude) in x and y variable and passing x and y argument into the getmap function.

```
    let map, searchManager;
    let directionsManager;

    // Requesting User location and generation of user's latitude and longitude
    if(navigator.geolocation){  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition) 
        
        }
        function showPosition(position){
            var x =  position.coords.latitude;
            var y =  position.coords.longitude;
            GetMap(x,y);
        }
```

> In Getmap function i am taking argument x and y  (latitude & longitude) and centering it into the map.
> Also within getmap function calling reverseGeocode() function for converting latitude & longitude into address name.

```
// Display the map and taking latitude and longitude to center the map
function GetMap(x,y) {
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
                credentials: 'Your credentials',
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location( x, y),
                zoom: 13
            });

        reverseGeocode();
}
```

> Defining reverseGeocode function and also giving alert to the user his address and printing the address in console.

```
// Reverse the geocode(latitude and longitude)
        function reverseGeocode() {
            //If search manager is not defined, load the search module.
            if (!searchManager) {
                //Create an instance of the search manager and call the reverseGeocode function again.
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                    searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                    reverseGeocode();
                });
            } else {
                var searchRequest = {
                    location: map.getCenter(),
                    callback: function (r) {
                        //Tell the user the name of the result.
                        alert(r.name);
                        console.log(r.name);
                    },
                    errorCallback: function (e) {
                        //If there is an error, alert the user about it.
                        alert("Unable to reverse geocode location.");
                    }
                };
    
                //Make the reverse geocode request.
                searchManager.reverseGeocode(searchRequest);
            }
        }
```